# What would yo do to adapt a Tilemap to different Screen Resolutions?

Tags: 2d

I'm working on a 2D mini-strategy game and i have a TileMap.

The main idea is that the TileMap fits in all Screen Resolutions without having to scroll over it and prevent giving view advantatge to higher resolutions respect lowers (more tiles displayed).

So this leaves me without not many choices I think?

- Scale the Tiles.
- TileMap as tiny as the lowest resolution i want to support, then filling the gaps of higher resolutions with something decorative?

Do i have other options? What would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your engine is built I'd say you can either:

Tinker with the second option - make use of something like an upgraded fog of war (shadow of war?) to reduce useful info taken from tiles outside your field of view to nothing.

In my opinion using "decoration" to fill space will give an unfinished touch to the game. You can consider this option though for the initial stages of the game.

Set a fixed field of view and implement something like a zoom-in/zoom-out so smaller screens can simply make use of that feature to get an overall view AND work with the game at ease by mouse scroll or whichever input method you find at hand.

Just scale them up for bigger screens BUT that can reduce quality of image unless you use antialias or vector-based images.

Edit: you can also combine any of these. Like the fog of war AND zoom-in/zoom-out